# how to create database in blackberry os 5.0 using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, blackberry, cordova

I need to create the database in blackberry os 5.0 using javascript for phonegap application.

```
    var mydb=false;
        function onLoad() {
        try {

      if (!window.openDatabase) {
     alert('not supported');
     } 
     else {
     var shortName = 'phonegap';
     var version = '0.9.4';
     var displayName = 'PhoneGap Test Database';
     var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
     mydb = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
    }
    } 
}
```

It is moving to if condition and only the alert is displayed.But the database is not getting created.Please tell me what's wrong in this code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does BlackBerry 5 even have openDatabase?

Comment: @ceejayoz openDatabase() is in the PhoneGap framework that the OP said he is using.

Answer (score 4):

You have your answer, no? If it's moving to the `if` and only the `alert` is being displayed, it's never going to go to the `else` and create the database, but there's a good reason for that. The `if` tests for support. Apparently, BlackBerry OS 5.0 doesn't support databases. You can check [this page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) for a list of polyfills to support HTML5 features in less capable browsers.

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry 5 is not supported by PhoneGap's openDatabase API.

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

> Supported Platforms
>
> - Android
> - BlackBerry WebWorks **(OS 6.0 and higher)**
> - iPhone

Answer (score 0):

HI Recently I had the same problem and I found a cool solution :D
BB5 have a **"Google Gear"** Iternaly in the browser to do that

```
  if (window.openDatabase){
        //HTML5
  }else{
     //try google GEARS
     if (window.google || google.gears){
        _DB = google.gears.factory.create('beta.database', '1.0');
        _DB.open('MyLocalDB');
        }

    }
```